# С начала 1990 года по некоторый день прошло n месяцев и 2 дня. Определить название месяца в этот день

Tags: c++, календарь

Написать программу используя
#include 
#include <windows.h>
и Switch

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Подскажу - в одном году 12 месяцев.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку n месяцев и 2 дня от начала года,, то это n-й месяц, а их в году 12, так что в псевдокоде -

```
{"Jan","Feb",...,"Dec"}[n%12]
```

Comment: Феврали в високосные годы еще надо учесть

Comment: @avp Не надо, промежуток же не в днях

Comment: @MBo, согласен (сам вопрос невнимательно прочел)